# Regex that match if the match contains special word

Tags: regex

i stumbled across a regex problem i cant solve. I want to match a part of a config file but only if it contains a special word:

```
{{START}}
    {{CONF1}}blah blah ..{{ENDCONF1}}
    {{CONF2}}blah blah ..{{ENDCONF2}}
{{END}}

{{START}}
    {{CONF1}}blah blah ..{{ENDCONF1}}
    {{CONF2}}blah specialword ..{{ENDCONF2}}
{{END}}

{{START}}
    {{CONF1}}blah blah ..{{ENDCONF1}}
    {{CONF2}}blah blah ..{{ENDCONF2}}
{{END}}
```

here i want to match the entire block which contains the "specialword"

```
{{START}}
    {{CONF1}}blah blah ..{{ENDCONF1}}
    {{CONF2}}blah specialword ..{{ENDCONF2}}
{{END}}
```

by playing around with some pattern i achieved the direct opposit with lookarounds "all that does not contain spacialword" but not the opposit, that i want :/

```
{{START}}((?!specialword)[\s\S])*?{{END}}
```

to be clear i want

```
{{START}}[\s\S]*?{{END}}
```

where the part that matches

```
[\s\S]*?
```

must contain the "specialword" to match the entire expression

Comment: Is that an XML file? If not, stick with `({{START}}[\s\S]*?specialword[\s\S]*?{{END}})`

Comment: @RubensFarias: That won't work correctly. In the above example, it will match the first two groups.

Comment: @RubensFarias: i did the same mistake ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're kind of on the right track with [lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
{{START}}(?:(?!{{END}})[\s\S])*specialword(?:(?!{{END}})[\s\S])*{{END}}
```

**Explanation:**

```
{{START}}      # Match {{START}}
(?:            # Match...
 (?!{{END}})   # ...as long as we haven't reached {{END}} yet:
 [\s\S]        # any character
)*             # any number of times.
specialword    # Match "specialword"
(?:            # Match (as before)...
 (?!{{END}})   # whatever follows, unless it's {{END}}
 [\s\S]
)*
{{END}}        # Then finally match {{END}}
```

Comment: Thanks for that super explanation! I had some sort of this in my mind but didnt know how to express that. I think i had to take a deeper look into that (?:) thing. I really appreciate your short and exact answer!